# Forward packets received to internet

Tags: networking, server, iptables

I currently have a weather station that I am trying to sniff packets from that also needs to communicate directly with the internet. My current setup, I configured a NAT rule in my firewall to forward data from the station to my Ubuntu server. I can successfully receive data from the station on the server, however in order to receive proper data the station needs to handshake with the internet.

So my question is, how can I keep my Ubuntu server in line between the station and the internet?

EDIT:
Just to clarity I had this resolved with my old router by peforming the below:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING  -s 192.168.0.7 -j ROUTE --tee --gw 192.168.0.8
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.7 -j ROUTE --tee --gw 192.168.0.8
```

My issue now is my new UniFi Security Gateway 3P does not accept the '--tee' target, I created the below NAT rules to get the data from my weather station to my ubuntu server:

```
set service nat rule 4500 destination port 80
set service nat rule 4500 source address 192.168.0.7
set service nat rule 4500 inbound-interface eth1
set service nat rule 4500 inside-address address 192.168.0.8
set service nat rule 4500 inside-address port 80
set service nat rule 4500 protocol tcp
set service nat rule 4500 type destination
```

But as mentioned before, this is a deadend and the station cannot communicate with the internet.

Notes:

```
192.167.0.1 = Gateway/USG
192.167.0.7 = Weather Station
192.167.0.8 = Ubuntu VM
```

Thanks in advance!

Kev

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to assign the weather station a default route through your ubuntu, it's going to be a lot prettier, now you'll have to NAT three times and that's not rock solid or easy to troubleshoot.

On the Ubuntu to set it up as an internet gateway instead of just an endpoint, you'll need to enable ip_forwarding and add a iptables rule to masquerade incoming traffic bound for the outgoing traffic to pretend it's coming from your ubuntu.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
```

You may also need to add a rule in your forward to explicitly allow forwarding traffic, this may be already by default accepting everything.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -j ACCEPT
```

This would match all incoming traffic not destined for your ubuntu (passing through), so it's if possible match it also with characteristics like source (-s) and/or destination (-d)

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 1.2.3.4 -d 5.6.7.8 -i enp0s3 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added a few notes above for clarity.

So in your example, I would perform the following on my Ubuntu Server:

sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE

And for the below, what would the destination be? The gateway on my USG? FYI this Ubuntu only has one network so I am not too sure on how to handle the eth2 and 3

iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.7 -d 192.168.0.1 -i eth2 -o eth3 -j ACCEPT

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!